# splitting a string in javascript to get data

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, algorithm

I have a string

```
"(1,4,76,465,567,583,590)"
```

I want to be able to put it into a javascript array

```
jArray[3] = 465 for example
```

how would I be able to parse a string into substrings of variable length to pass as numbers?

Answer (score 3):

Just replace all `(`, `)` and all whitespace characters with empty string; split it with `,` and then apply `parseInt` function over all the elements to convert them to numbers, like this

```
var data = "(1,4,76,465,567,583,590)";
console.log(data.replace(/[\s()]/g, "").split(",").map(function(currentItem) {
    return parseInt(currentItem);
}));
```

**Output**

```
[ 1, 4, 76, 465, 567, 583, 590 ]
```

If you don't want to convert them to numbers, then you are better off with

```
data.replace(/[\s()]/g, "").split(",");
```

If your environment doesn't support [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function yet, you can use the following

```
var splittedNumbers = data.replace(/[\s()]/g, "").split(",");
for (var i = 0; i < splittedNumbers.length; i += 1) {
    splittedNumbers[i] = parseInt(splittedNumbers[i]);
}
console.log(splittedNumbers);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well first you will need to get rid of the brackets.

```
var string = "(1,4,76,465,567,583,590)";
string = string.replace(/[()]/g,'');
```

That will return

```
"1,4,76,465,567,583,590"
```

So all you need to do now is use the split() method

```
var array = string.split(',');
```

That will return string values so you will need to also pass them through parseInt() method.

Answer (score 0):

Add the new method to the String prototype which removes the `(` and `)` and then split's by comma

```
String.prototype.splitString = function () {
    return this.replace('(', '').replace(')', '').split(',').map(function (current) { return parseInt(current) });
};

var string = "(1,2,3,456,567,543,232)";

var array = string.splitString();
```

**Output**

```
[1, 2, 3, 456, 567, 543, 232]
```

Comment: OP wants an array of integers not strings.

Comment: Noted.  Updated the answer